# Linux using swap instead of RAM with large image processing

Tags: linux, r, memory

I'm processing large images on a Linux server using the R programming language, so I expect much of the RAM to be used in the image processing and file writing process.

However, the server is using swap memory long before it appears to need to, thus slowing down the processing time significantly.  See following image:

[image]

This shows I am using roughly 50% of the RAM for the image processing, about 50% appears to be reserved for disk cache (yellow) and yet 10Gb of swap is being used!

I was watching the swap being eaten up, and it didn't happen when the RAM was any higher in use than is being shown in this image.  The swap appears to be eaten up during the processed data being written to a GeoTiff file.

My working theory is that the disk writing process is using much of the disk cache area (yellow region), and therefore the yellow isn't actually available to the server (as is often assumed of disk cache RAM)?

Does that sound reasonable?  Is there another reason for swap being used when RAM is apparently available?

Comment: Does your user have a quota on system resources? Though AFAIK you can be limited on total address space, and you won't get any *extra* swap if you exceed it.

Comment: No, my user has no memory limit quota.  I have in the past used memory up to 64Gb without using swap.  It appears to be happening for this scenario only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may be affected by [swappiness](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/System/Linux%20Memory%20Management.htm) kernel parameter:

> When an application needs memory and all the RAM is fully occupied, the kernel has two ways to free some memory at its disposal: it can either reduce the disk cache in the RAM by eliminating the oldest data or it may swap some less used portions (pages) of programs out to the swap partition on disk. It is not easy to predict which method would be more efficient. The kernel makes a choice by roughly guessing the effectiveness of the two methods at a given instant, based on the recent history of activity.
>
> Swappiness takes a value between 0 and 100 to change the balance between swapping applications and freeing cache. At 100, the kernel will always prefer to find inactive pages and swap them out. A value of 0 gives something close to the old behavior where applications that wanted memory could shrink the cache to a tiny fraction of RAM.

If you want to force the kernel to avoid swapping whenever possible and give the RAM from device buffers and disk cache to your application, you can set swappiness to zero:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
```

Note that you may actually worsen the performace with this setting, because your disk cache may shrink to a tiny fraction of what it is now, making disk access slower.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for your post.  It would seem that in this instance then, the swappiness may be giving priority to the disk cache as it believes it will be needed.  It is therefore quite possibly the correct thing to be doing given the large files my application is writing.

Comment: I would be interested to know what happens to the performance if you reduce swappiness to a reasonably small value (i.e. 20-30).

Comment: I was intending to do just that actually, and I will let you know, unfortunately I need the server to be running jobs at present which will confuse the RAM usage.  However I will do exactly that as soon as possible.

Comment: @SingleEntity: Seems that it would depend on if you are planning to read those files back after writing them. If you are doing a write and forget, then the cache is useless.

Comment: @ZanLynx Some amount of caching is still useful in a "write and forget" scenario. Grouping write operations will make the life easier for block allocator.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev: True, if you are using a filesystem with delayed block allocation like ext4 or btrfs. Still, you don't need gigabytes of file cache.